# How to implement CDN caching with s-maxage header

Tags: http, http-headers, cdn, akamai

I am trying to cache a dynamic web page in a CDN for about 900 seconds and no caching in the browser. And ater the 900 seconds i want the CDN to get the latest copy of the dynamic web page and save that into the cache.

I can do this by setting cache-control:s-maxage=600,max-age=0

But how do i tell the CDN to jo and fetch the latest content after 900 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the TTL for that webpage say 900sec in CDN configuration and then you can disable downstream caching in the same. No changes needed in Origin. Which CDN are you using ?